# Just started with Java, I think I need to include new classes.

Tags: java, html, firefox, render, incompatibility

I added my new classes to the end of an xcode java project creator and Firefox says it doesn't support Java so it won't load any of my options, which may or may not be correctly formatted. I'm sure I should be including new classes but does anyone have any suggestions. I've only studied the basics and the websites I'm trying to use to learn java are very limited or technically down at the moment. I've tried to convert it to HTML but I think the online converters are outdated. Is there anyway to generate HTML from Java codes so that my program will render somewhat?

```
//
//  Hovercraft.java
//  Hovercraft
//
//  Created by Getting Nifty on 12/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//
//  A simple signed Java applet
//

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hovercraft extends JApplet {

    static final String message = "Hello World!";
    private Font font = new Font("serif", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 36);

    public void init() {
    // set the default look and feel
    String laf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException exc) {
        System.err.println ("Warning: UnsupportedLookAndFeel: " + laf);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.err.println ("Error loading " + laf + ": " + exc);
    }
    getContentPane().setLayout (null);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(message, 40, 80);
    }

    public class interface int class Hovercraft1 {
    forward()

    backward()

    rotateTo(int angle,booleanimmediateReturn)  
stop()

    public waitForPress1(Go)

    public waitForPress2(Stop)

    public waitforPress3(idle)

    static drawString(String str, int x, int y)

    static shutOff(waitForPress2)

    static turnOn(waitForPress1)

    static boolean(isMoving)

    static boolean(isRunning)

    public isStop

    public isMoving

    public isRunning

    public idle

    public ProcessVoidStore
    static ProcessReturn 3/4 x Null
    static ProcessCorrectSlow(

    static boolean(isStop)
    println.txt Stopping

    static boolean(isGo)

    status.println(waitForPressn)


    rotateTo(int angle,booleanimmediateReturn)
    ifClass(isStop) 

    public class xTurn
    public class xTurn2
    public class Obstruction
    public class RoadDebree(if class Change)
    int class Change 

    int class airPressure
    int class Vacuum1Pressure
    int class Vacuum2Pressure
    int class Vacuum3Pressure
    int class Vacuum4Pressure

    boolean class Balloon

    int class BalloonClose(Balloon%)

    int stop args(boolean open Balloon; boolean close Balloon%; vacuum1, vacuum2, vacuum3, vacuum4)



}
```

Comment: You might read up on the topic a bit more and clarify your question. I dont have the slightest idea what your talking about

Comment: HTML5, canvas etc. Applets are dead. If really need to write in Java, try gwt.

Answer (score 2):

You need JSP (Java Server Pages) and rename your file extension to .jsp instead of .html . I recommend doing a JSP tutorial.
WIth JSP you'll pretty much have an HTML page with Java code running inside it doing stuff.